# Drop using several MultiIndex levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndexed dataframe like this:

```
      foo
c b a
p 6 1 3.0
q 7 2 2.3
r 8 3 1.0
s 9 4 100.0
```

I can use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to get rid of several rows using the first `n` MultiIndex levels like this:

```
>>> x.drop([('p', 6), ('r',8)])
      foo
c b a
q 7 2 2.3
s 9 4 100.0
```

I can also [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) from a single level:

```
>>> x.drop([1, 2], level='a')
      foo
c b a
r 8 3 1.0
s 9 4 100.0
```

But I don't seem to be able to do this for multiple levels (other than the first `n`):

```
>>> x.drop([(8, 3), (9, 4)], level=['b', 'a'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-156-a650ded10561>", line 1, in <module>
    x.drop([(8, 3), (9, 4)], level=['b', 'a'])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1399, in drop
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2718, in drop
    return self._drop_from_level(labels, level)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2744, in _drop_from_level
    i = self._get_level_number(level)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 2199, in _get_level_number
    raise KeyError('Level %s not found' % str(level))

KeyError: "Level ['b', 'a'] not found"
```

This seems odd because [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) *does* accept a list of levels, as per the example:

```
>>> df.xs(('baz', 2), level=[0, 'third'])
        A  B  C  D
second
three   5  3  5  3
```

So how can I drop `[(8, 3), (9, 4)]` (i.e. the 3rd and 4th rows) from my dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

This functionaility is not there yet, see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6599

You can do this however.

```
In [19]: mask = df.index.get_level_values

In [20]: df.loc[~(mask('b').isin([8,9]) & mask('a').isin([3,4]))]
Out[20]: 
       foo
c b a     
p 6 1  3.0
q 7 2  2.3
```